# How to copy folders older than a specific date with Powershell 2.0

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a number of folders that I am trying to copy. The folders are all name 'yyyymmdd' i.e. 20190615, going back up to a year or more. I am trying to figure out a way to copy only the last 45 days of these folders. The biggest issue that I've run into is that the computers that I am running this on only have Powershell 2.0, which seems to have some limitations that 5 or greater does not have.

I have been able to get the list of all of the folders in the path with :

```
$datedsubs = Get-ChildItem -path $path | where-object { $_ -like "20*" }
```

From there though, I am a little stuck. I feel this would be easier with PS 5 or greater. I've tried Robocopy, even though that is not a PS solution, but that copies everything, and I just want the folders.

I've tried something like the following, but it doesn't seem to work in PS 2.0.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object { ($_ -like '20*') -and ($_.LastAccessTime -lt $datedlimit)} | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse
```

Any help would be appreciated here.

Thanks

Comment: get the list with `Get-ChildItem`, filter out the files with `.PSIsContainer`, sort by name [the date strings will sort neatly as they are], then use `Select-Object -Index (1..5)` to get the 1st 5 items.

Comment: robocopy might work with [e xf *](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0b3d3006-0e0f-4c95-9e2f-4c820832ebfa/using-robocopy-to-copy-folder-structure-only?forum=w7itprogeneral) ```robocopy 20* /e /xf * /maxage:20151231``` with [maxage](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2a77d7cf-95e2-4955-b98b-023c5da6aa5b/copy-files-from-a-specfied-date-range?forum=winserverfiles)

Comment: @Harlan - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Putting what Lee has said into some code.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "20*" | Where-Object {($_.PSIsContainer) `
    -and ($_.LastAccessTime -gt ((Get-Date).AddDays(-45)))} | `
    Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Recurse
```

This should get you what you are after.

I have put it to `-gt` 45 days ago because this will only show folders accessed within the last 45 days.